# Reference request- Orthogonal polynomials

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, inner-products, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm looking for reference to literature on the subject of orthogonal polynomials. I am specifically intersted with the following problem:

Let $\omega$ be a compactly supported density function on $\mathbb{R}$, contionuous except perhaps on the edges of it's support. I define an "inner product":

$$ \langle f,g \rangle_{\omega}:= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)g(t)\omega(t)dt$$

I want to find a sequence of polynomials, $\{ P_n \}_{n=0}^\infty $, such that:

(i) Orthogonal with respect to this inner product, $\langle P_m,P_n\rangle_{\omega}=0$ if $m\neq n$.

(ii) $\deg(P_n)=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

(iii) For $\text{supp}(\omega)\subseteq[a,b]$, $\{ P_n \}$ is dense in $L^2[a,b]$.

I do not have too much previous knowledge on the subject,  so I hope there are literature which assume an introduction to the subject.

Comment: Try to prove that the $P_n$ are uniquely determined by (1)--(2). For this you may obviously assume that the leading coefficient of each $P_n$ is $1$. AND: Do you want the $P_n$ to be dense or their span? The latter follows from (1) and (2).

Comment: Hints: Gram-Schmidt for 1 and 2, and Weierstrass approximation for 3 (assuming you meant "span").

Comment: There is vast literature on orthogonal polynomials.  The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials) and references therein may be a place to get started.

Comment: I did mean span, and I am aware that the Weierstrass approximation theorem implies (iii). But I am trying to give an explicit expression, so I was hoping that literature on the subject would perhaps help in the calculation of the integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So classical references on orthogonal polynomials are:
"Classical and Quantum orthogonal polynomials in one variable" by M E H Ismail and
"Orthogonal Polynomials" by G Szegö.

From your comment it seems you are interested in explicit expressions so
"Hypergeometric Orthogonal Polynomials and Their q-Analogues" by Roelof Koekoek, Peter A. Lesky, René F. Swarttouw
could be especially useful.

If this is all a bit too much information I can recommend the introductory part of "Orthogonal Polynomials and Painlevé Equations" by Walter Van Assche, to get a quick idea.